# Count non-empty cells that fulfill a criterion

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Here is something that should be basic, but I cant' figure it out.

So, I have information in columns A:G. Some of the cells in columns B:G are empty, others not.

In the following spreadsheet, how do I find out how many cells in the area B:G are non-empty provided the criterion "John" is filled in column A:A?

My try, which does not work:
`=COUNTIFS(A:A, "John", B:G, "*")`

```
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+
|    |   A   |    B    |    C    |    D    |   E   |     F     |   G    |
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | John  | bla     | blaba   | fsdfs   |       | sdfsdfdsf | sdfsdf |
|  2 | Bill  | sfsdf   |         | sdfsdf  |       | sdfsdsd   |        |
|  3 | Tim   |         |         |         |       |           |        |
|  4 | John  | sdfsdf  | ssdfsdf |         |       | sdfsdf    | sdfsd  |
|  5 | Rick  | egerreg | g       | gergerg |       | g         |        |
|  6 | Steve |         |         |         | ergrg |           |        |
|  7 | Rick  | ergerg  | er      | gergerg |       |           |        |
|  8 | John  |         | reger   |         |       |           | erge   |
|  9 | Tim   |         | erg     |         | erg   |           |        |
| 10 | Rick  | ergerg  |         |         |       | ergerg    | erge   |
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Please amend your question to give sample data and examples of what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, so I converted my spreadsheet to code on this page https://senseful.github.io/text-table/, as suggested by other users, but as you can see, the code does not turn out nicely, but is completely misaligned... What do I do wrong? How should I add code?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. It *is* fairly basic. You can do it with:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="John")*(NOT(ISBLANK((B1:G10)))))
```

or

```dart
{=SUM((A1:A10="John")*(NOT(ISBLANK((B1:G10)))))}
```

The second formula is array-entered, of course.

Note that while the formula would still work if you used entire columns, this is not recommended as the formula will take a long time to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft Office help center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1036&UiLcid=1036&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60529&omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) regarding `COUNTIFS`:

> Important: Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

Which is the reason why your `COUNTIFS` fails: the argument `B:G` doesn't have the same number of columns as the first argument, `A:A`.

---

One way to achieve this would be to use a `SUMPRODUCT`, which doesn't have this size limitation.

You can use, as RobinCTS suggested, the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="John")*(NOT(ISBLANK(B1:E6))))
```

However, if a cell has a `0` inside, it won't be considered empty.

---

An alternative solution to Robin's answer, is to use the fact that both an empty cell and a cell that contains a `0` will return `TRUE` when tested to these conditions: `<>0` and `<>""`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="John")*(B1:E6<>0))
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="John")*(B1:E6<>""))
```

Depending on what you need, and the kind of data contained in your workbook, one of these 2 solutions should work.

This is illustrated in the example below:

[image]